# I am new to this pls suggest mez

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please guide me to do a simple robot new to this of course.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269353/i-am-new-to-this-pls-suggest-mez/) by [Ashin](https://answers.ros.org/users/31662/ashin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can start with this:

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [gerard](https://answers.ros.org/users/31585/gerard/) with karma: 46 on 2017-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3